# Ant: how do I disable all non-error messages?

Tags: command-line, ant, build-process, warnings

When running ant from command line on my Netbeans projects, I get the following messages hundreds of times, which is very annoying:

```
Trying to override old definition of task http://www.netbeans.org/ns/j2se-project/3:javac
Trying to override old definition of task http://www.netbeans.org/ns/j2se-project/3:depend
Trying to override old definition of task http://www.netbeans.org/ns/j2se-project/1:nbjpdastart
Trying to override old definition of task http://www.netbeans.org/ns/j2se-project/3:debug
Trying to override old definition of task http://www.netbeans.org/ns/j2se-project/1:java
```

Depending of the kind of the project, there can be much more of such lines.

And this is **with** the `-q` or `-quiet` option.

Any idea, how to disable this message?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of a hack, but if you are on a unix like system, perhaps do:

```
alias ant="ant | grep -v 'Trying to override old definition of task'"
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I'm on Linux ;)